# Are izakaya where the bartender doesn't stand opposite the bar inauthentic?

Tags: japan, restaurants, local-knowledge

Most izakaya I've been to have the bartender standing on the other side of the bar, or even consist solely of a bar.

However, I've been to two places that called themselves an izakaya where the bartender is not on the opposite side of the bar. In one of them, the bar faced a wall, while in the other, the bar formed an oblong shape.

One of them seemed to be part of a chain of izakayas, which made me think it was an inauthentic rip-off of an izakaya, a place that was more izakaya-themed than a genuine izakaya. The other was in a touristy area of the touristy town of Takayama, which also made me suspicious that it was an inauthentic rip-off targeting people who wouldn't know what a real izakaya is like.

Are such places regarded as real izakayas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45552/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-grimm-are-izakaya-where-the-bartender-doesnt-s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.   Many, many izakayas, including all the large chains I know of (Watami, Shirokiya, Tengu etc) consist entirely of private booths of various sizes, with service direct from kitchen to booth, and thus **don't have a "bar" in any sense of the word**, much less bartenders standing behind it.

An izakaya is *literally* a "stay-sake-shop" (居酒屋), meaning a place that sells alcohol for consumption on premises.  And because you traditionally eat while you drink in Japan, izakayas serve food, and I'd even posit that **this** is the dividing line between a izakaya and a (Western-style) bar, not the location or presence of the bar.

Delineating where an izakaya ends and a restaurant starts is an even tougher exercise.  I like @TheWanderingCoder's definition of izakayas being primarily for drinking, while restaurants are primarily for eating, but even that can be a pretty fuzzy line in both directions: there are plenty of "gourmet izakayas" that would be restaurants if they called themselves that, and (for example) *yakiniku* grilled-meat restaurants that also offer all-you-can-drink deals and are primarily intended for people who want to get hammered.

Comment: I don't anticipate trying to fix my question tonight Japan time. An izakaya being part of a chain doesn't fit what I initially assumed would be regarded as an authentic izakaya - is this assumption also wrong?

Comment: A chain pub is still a pub, just not necessarily a good one. Same for izakayas. Also, plenty of non-chain izakaya also do the all-booth thing.

Comment: I've added some information on why I thought such places are inauthentic to the question. Have I communicated my reasoning well, regardless of whether it's based on incorrect, outdated, or insufficient information?

Comment: the "chain" aspect discussed, just re-emphasizes that outside Japan, "izakaya" appears to have an "authentic" and/or "high-end" connotation - that, it seems to me, is entirely missing actually in Japan.  consider the western word "restaurant".  it's completely value-free.  you can have Le Meurice or, McDonalds as a "restaurant" as normal use of the word.  Same.

Comment: "pub" is a great example.  the word can be used for the most achingly authentic traditional "british pub", or it can be used for a crappy franchize pub.